# while running the react native app i got the error path could not be found within the project or in these directories:node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my code I am using react-native: 0.66.1 and I  have installed dotenv: ^10.0.0.
.env file code

```
API_LOGIN=https://example.in/login
```

app.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
class UserLogin extends Component{
   //some code here
   apiCallHere=()=>{
      const url=process.env.API_LOGIN;
      fetch(url,{
         method: 'POST',  
         body: JSON.stringify({   
            email: email,
            password: password
         }),
         headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         })
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error))
            
      .then((response) => {
         if (response.access_token != undefined) {
            this.setState({
               accessToken : response.access_token,
            });
            if(this.state.accessToken != ''){
               this.props.navigation.navigate('UserHomePage');
            }
         }
         else{
            alert('Unauthorised User');
         }
      })
   }
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem. I am not able to find the problem. I am new in react native

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root folder where your package.json file is (Terminal: cd /path/your_app):

> 1. Install Dotenv - npm i dotenv
> 2. Import in your file (server.js / your_app_file.js) - require("dotenv").config();
> 3. Make the .env file (Terminal: touch .env && nano .env)
> 4. Add your secrets and save then test

This works for me, i am using Node.js/Express for server-side and i am using also React for client side with .env and REACT_APP_{SECRETS} then in App.js you add where you need this line - process.env.REACT_APP_SECRETS.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem lies in the import method

Try changing the require to import

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()
```

Please let me know if it works

Comment: It's not worked for me.

Comment: Please give me another solution